# How to charge an Android Emulator while working in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator

I have already tried with following process:

1. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
   2 .On the Control Panel Home page, click Programs.
2. In the Programs and Features section, click Turn Windows features on or off.
3. If the User Account Control dialog box appears, confirm that the action it displays is what you want, and then click Continue.
4. In the Windows Features list, select Telnet Client, and then click OK.

After successful installations, run the same telnet command.

iii). Type:
power capacity 100

After following the mentioned process, emulator stops working? 
If anyone could help me in this regard, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Is it only the power command that makes the emulator stop? Try running other commands on telnet and let me know

If it is only power that does not work then try this

In your avd manager check the details of your emulator. See to it that hw.battery is yes and then run your emulator again and try using the power capacity 100 command from telnet localhost. It should work

Answer (score 0):

use telnet command:
power status discharging